# Bad return from wordpress database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have custom post type named universities. When trying to show it in admin page (where are all listed), it shows me total posts 25, first page is fine, when I click to second page, it shows some same results from first page and some are really missing. When I try to find them (upper right), they shows ... What can be problem? In my database it looks fine, trying to turn off every plugins but doesnt help.

I found one interesting thing.... When showing queries on my DB, this query is queriing:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'universities'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 20, 20
```

It returns this ID: 1194, 1193, 1192, 1191, 1190

And that is bad (this ID are part of posts in first page, not second one), because when I run same query like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'universities'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 20, 20
```

In results there are another IDs: 1204,1205,1206,1207,1208

And this is what I need to get from first post ... What I can check to fix this error? I tried everything I think :/

Comment: The 2 queries you're running are not the same. `wp_posts.ID` and `wp_posts.*` for example.

Comment: only that is change ... But that shouldnt make different results in ID, and thats unbelievable to me, that results are not the same :)

Comment: Why are you using `LIMIT 20,20` ?

Comment: If you remove `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` does it give the same results with `wp_posts.ID` and `wp_posts.*`? Try running the query in a database management tool like Navicat.

Comment: Its not me, its wordpress way how it work with pagination ... but when I remove that, it doesnt change results same for @Andy

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it "doesn't change results" - does this mean you're getting *the same* results as on your post.... or that the results from running the 2 separate queries is identical? I can't see how you could get different result sets from 2 identical queries, especially if you've removed `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. The only difference between `wp_posts.ID` and `wp_posts.*` is that the latter will select more columns where as the former only selects one (the `ID` field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found solution and reason why is like that. Problem was, that I imported posts from wp all import. It´s all right, but it has been imported at same time and all post date was same for most posts. So, when my DB call request, all posts has same time, so order by wp_posts.post_date make problem, when there is limit. It is the reason, why in one select return differents id´s against second select, and also reason why in my admin pages wordpress shows two same posts.

I solve it by changing post dates for posts to random number in specific range and everything works insane :)